# WordPress conditional not working

Tags: wordpress

I need to hide a specific portion of my footer file if the page being displayed is the "artists page". The content i was told to hide was all jumbled together in the footer so i separated that part, and placed it in its own file. lets call that file, **file X.php**, which I placed back on the footer via an include.

This is the link that's telling me that my page id is "4":

```
wp-admin/post.php?post=4&action=edit
```

I need file X.php to only show, when the page being shown to the user is not artists page. So essentially, i need file X.php to show on every page except the artists page.

I used a simple conditional like so:

```
if ( ! is_page( 'artists' ) ) { include('file X.php'); } 
//i used this to target the page by page name
```

/=========

```
if ( ! is_page( '4' ) ) { include('file X.php'); }
//i used this to target the page by page id
```

and the page never hides. its always shown.

i referenced this link/page: https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

and other pages like it, including posts here on SO but yeah, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I don't get any errors or anything broken. When i leave that code in place(by page title or id), the footer shows as its supposed on the other pages, but unfortunately shows on the artists page as well when i need it not to.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

EDIT***

i used: `var_dump( get_queried_object() );`

and this is what it returned:

```
object(stdClass)#376 (17) { 
    ["term_id"]=> &int(3) 
    ["name"]=> &string(15) "featuredArtists" 
    ["slug"]=> &string(15) "featuredartists" 
    ["term_group"]=> int(0) 
    ["term_order"]=> string(2) "11" 
    ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(3) 
    ["taxonomy"]=> string(8) "category" 
    ["description"]=> &string(0) "" 
    ["parent"]=> &int(0) 
    ["count"]=> &int(3) 
    ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" 
    ["cat_ID"]=> &int(3) 
    ["category_count"]=> &int(3) 
    ["category_description"]=> &string(0) "" 
    ["cat_name"]=> &string(15) "featuredArtists" 
    ["category_nicename"]=> &string(15) "featuredartists" 
    ["category_parent"]=> &int(0) 
}
```

Comment: Paste `var_dump( get_queried_object() )` in the footer, go to the page in question and paste the result in your question

Comment: i added the var_dump, i put the result at the bottom of the post

Answer (score 1):

Remove `query_posts`. `get_queried_object()` should return the page object regardless of what is being showed on it.

As you can see from the `var_dump()`, a category object is returned where as it **should** return the page object, which means that `is_page()` will **always** return false although it is a true page. `is_category()` will return true on this page however as the page has been set as a category page.

What all of this means is that the main query object changed on the page, and the only function that can do that is `query_posts` (*or you have used `$wp_query` as a local variable to assign a custom query to it*). This is the main reason why you should **never ever** use `query_posts` as it breaks the main query object, it sets the main query object to the current custom query, which breaks all the conditionals and the queried object. Just for interest sake, **before and after** your `query_posts( 'cat=3' );`, add `var_dump( is_page() );` and `var_dump( is_category() );` and check the results.

As solution, switch to `WP_Query` to run custom queries with (*or use `get_posts` for non paginated queries*)